# Computing the discrete log in cyclic group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Say we are given the following cyclic group $G$ which is generated by $g$ element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. In this case $g=13$ and $p=23$ so $13$ element of $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$.

If there exists two random $g$ values in the cyclic group $G$, how does one go about computing the discrete log in $G$?

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331760/computing-the-discrete-log-in-cyclic-group-g?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Say $g=8$.  Then since $8\cong {13^2}\pmod{23}$, we say the discrete log of $8$ with respect to the base $13$ mod $23$ is $2$.

You can write $2=\operatorname {ind}_{13}8\pmod{23}$.  (Gauß called it the *index*.)

I chose an easy example.   These can be difficult to compute, which must be why they are used in *cryptography*.